# C++ generating random numbers in a loop using default_random_engine

Tags: c++, random

Recently I was trying out a program on generating random numbers in C++ using the `random engines` defined in `#include<random>`. My program goes as follows :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
int random (int lim)
{
    default_random_engine dre (chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
    uniform_int_distribution<> uid(1,lim);
    return uid(dre);
}
int main()
{
    for (int i=0;i<10;++i)
    cout<<random(100)<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

Simple, definitely ! But when I tried the output the numbers were less random like these :-

```
66 95 95 96 96 96 96 96 97 97
```

When I changed my program slightly & declared the `default_random_engine` as `static` or made it `global` then my output was proper such as this :-

```
62 53 21 38 7 51 46 40 86 12
```

Could anyone point out what actually was going wrong in my program initially & how did the small change help me get a better output ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time you run `random` you reseed the generator with the same or very close to the same seed so you get the same output each iteration or if it does change it will not be by much.

To fix this you only seed the generator once and then keep calling it.  By making it static it works as expected as the generator is only created and seeded once you so keep going on its random sequence instead of getting the first random number it would create.

Typically random number generators have an internal value that they put through an algorithm and what the algorithm spits out is what they return for a random number.  That number is then retained for the next iteration of the algorithm.  This is how we get an random sequence.

If we use the same seed we will get the same output sequence as we start from the same number.  In your case your seed will only change each time  `chrono::steady_clock::now()` advances and your loop is running faster than that so you are getting the same time(seed) each call.

Comment: how does calling it once help anyway, afterall i m calling the loop again & again, you logic works for the first case but why does the STATIC case work well

Comment: "Very close seed" shouldn't result in the same output, the problem here is repeated seeding with the same seed value. The OP would probably get better results by switching to `high_resolution_clock` instead of `steady_clock`. A better fix, of course, is to not keep reseeding as you suggest.

Comment: @Praetorian "high_resolution_clock" is also not working well

Comment: @Anwesha: probably it's not high resolution enough, after all you are calling it in a tight loop, there are maybe 100 instructions between each call, so either it's using rdtsc or it's going to reseed each time with the same value. But the point is as already explained: you have to seed just *once* and then keep using the same random engine object.

Comment: I want to echo that 'very close seeds' are not a problem. Seeds incremented by one should produce sequences that appear completely independent. (Though of course that doesn't mean time is a good sole source of seed data.)

Comment: @bames53 Agree but generally the starting number of the sequence will be close.  Since the OP was only ever getting the first number from the sequence I included that.

Answer (score 1):

One important thing to know about pseudo random number generators is that they produce a sequence of numbers, and 'randomness' is a quality that the *sequence* is tested for. That is, you can't say that a particular number is random or not ([is '4' a random number?](https://xkcd.com/221/)). You instead say whether the sequence of numbers is random or not.

When you "seed" a pRNG you are generally selecting one of the sequences it can generate, and those numbers are random with respect to the rest of the sequence. So in general if you want 'randomness' you want to first select a particular sequence and then to use successive numbers from that particular random sequence.

In your code without `static`, you're selecting a sequence on each iteration of the loop, and then using one number from that sequence. Since you're not using many values from the same sequence it's not really much surprise that the result doesn't look random.

When you add `static` the engine is no longer being seeded on each iteration of the loop. Instead it's seeded once and each iteration of the loop uses successive values from that sequence, just like you're supposed to do. And this is what `static` means on block scoped variables: it means that the variable lives externally to the block it's declared in and that it will only be initialized the first time.

`static` does fix your problem, however I would argue that it's not a good solution. `static` variables have some similarities to global variables and cause some of the same problems. Instead what I would recommend is for you to explicitly move the engine outside the loop. For example:

```
int random (int lim, default_random_engine &dre)
{
    uniform_int_distribution<> uid(1,lim);
    return uid(dre);
}

int main()
{
    default_random_engine dre (chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        cout << random(100, dre) << " ";
    }
}
```

Now the state is being explicitly managed and passed into the `random()` function, which is better than relying on the hidden and implicit behavior of a block scoped `static` variable.

---

Also in general I would not recommend using time as a sole source of seed data. A low resolution clock might not provide new seeds frequently enough, and the program being run in different places at the same time can use the same seed.

My recommendation for seeding is:

```
std::random_device r;
std::seed_seq seed{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()};
std::mt19937 eng(seed);
```

(There's no need for beginners to know what mt19937 or any of the other bits are about. They just need to know to paste this at the appropriate location and how to use `eng`. In your code you'd need to replace each use of `default_random_engine` with `mt19937`.)