# C++ how to stop a random engine from producing negative numbers?

Tags: c++, random

I have a function that im trying to produce random numbers between 18 and 5

```
int randomAge() {
  int random;
  std::random_device rd;
  static std::default_random_engine generator(rd()); //produce a static random engine
  std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(18, 52);  //random age between 18 and 52
  random = distribution(generator);
  return random;
}
```

However I am recieving negative numbers and even numbers that are higher than 52. How can I fix this so it produces numbers between 18 and 52?

Comment: You want a uniform distribution, not a normal distribution. Google it

Comment: `std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(18, 52);` is a normal distribution with a mean value of 18 and standard deviation of 52. Negative numbers are to be expected here.

Comment: Very simplified, a uniform distribution with those parameters is centered around 18, and most (68%) of the numbers it produce are in the (18-52; 18+52) = (-34; 70) range.

Comment: Sidenote: Your `randomAge()` function will seed a new PRNG every time it's called. You should normally only see one PRNG (per thread) once and use it for the rest of the program's execution.

Answer (score 6):

You're using `std::normal_distribution` which generates random numbers according to the Normal (or Gaussian) random number distribution. You're using [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution/normal_distribution) constructor:

```cpp
explicit normal_distribution( RealType mean, RealType stddev = 1.0 );
```

What you want is `std::uniform_real_distribution`. See the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution):

> Produces random floating-point values i, uniformly distributed on the interval [a, b)

Do note that your engine and distribution must be `thread_local` (or `static`) and the random device can be a temporary. Otherwise your results are not uniformly distributed. You should also consider getting a random integer instead of double since the return type is `int` anyway:

```
#include <random>

int randomAge() {
  thread_local std::mt19937 engine{ std::random_device{}() };
  thread_local std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution{ 18, 52 };
  return distribution(engine);
}
```

Related:

- [Should I use std::default_random_engine or should I use std::mt19937?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30240899/10147399)
- [Is a Mersenne-twister cryptographically secure if I truncate the output?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12426/64624)

Answer (score 3):

[`std::normal_distribution<T>(mean,sd)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution/normal_distribution)(<-clickable link) produces a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)(<-clickable link) with a mean (middle point) of `mean` and a standard deviation ('spread') of `sd`.

If you want a uniform spread between two numbers, you need to use a [`std::uniform_real_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution)(<-clickable link).